# FFMPEG input file path for decyption

Tags: ffmpeg, encryption, input, decryption, help-files

I am using the code:

**ffmpeg -decryption_key {key} -i {file} -vcodec libx264 {output_file}**

But if I give input file arguments as "I:\Video.mp4" It shows that
'Invalid Argument'.

Comment: Why aren't you using "-i path-to-file" ?